# Hyperledger Fabric: How to get organization4 & 5 in test-network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

the hyperledger fabric samples test network is running on my ubuntu maschine.

For the next step I was running the addorg3.sh script, so I have 3 orgs in my network.

But for the next step I need more organizations, so how can I get them into my network?

I was trying to change parameters in the addorg3.sh script, but that was the wrong way I think.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Adding another organisation is quite complex. The point of the add org3 components in test-network is to highlight the steps and information required to add another organisation, so the recommendation here would be to read the hyperledger fabric documentation and study the test-network approach on adding an organisation. From there you would be able to work out how to add another organisation to the test network.

Comment: + peer channel join -b mychannel.block
+ res=1
2021-12-08 10:39:42.826 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500: cannot create ledger from genesis block: LedgerID already exists)

Thats my error in the last step joyning org4 to mychannel with org1/org2/org3.

peer channel join -b mychannel.block

Is there a common solution?